# Is it possible to recover the original sub DataFrames after they have been appended into a larger DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The code below appends two sub DataFrames df1 and df2 into one large dateframe:

```
     df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                     "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]}) 

     df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3], 
                "b":[5, 6, 7]}) 

     df1.append(df2)
```

Gives:

ab
  --
0| 15
1| 26
2| 37
3| 48
0| 15
1| 26
2| 37

Is it possible to split this appended DataFrame into the original sub DataFrames as shown below?

ab
  --
0| 15
1| 26
2| 37
3| 48

ab
  --
0| 15
1| 26
2| 37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
d={x : y for x,y in df.groupby((df.index==0).cumsum())}   

d[1]
Out[434]: 
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```